# how to get transaction supporting proxy from spring application context?

Tags: spring, transactional, applicationcontext

i need to use bean from spring application context not in a spring managed bean, so i do next: annotate bean with @Service annotation, so instance of bean created during spring loading.

```
<bean id="customRevisionListener" class="ru.csbi.registry.services.impl.envers.CustomRevisionListener" />
```

This instance is ApplicationContextAware, so application context is injected in this bean instance and i save it to static variable:

```
@Service 
public class CustomRevisionListener implements EntityTrackingRevisionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private ModelInformationService modelInformationService;    

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    CustomRevisionListener.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

private ModelInformationService getModelInformationService() {
    if (modelInformationService == null) {
        modelInformationService = applicationContext.getBean(ModelInformationService.class);
    }
//      TransactionProxyFactoryBean
    return modelInformationService;
}
```

After that another instance of CustomRevisionListener created in not spring context(hibernate envers context). Here i use static variable to receive spring applicationContext

after that i'm getting beans from application context:

```
private ModelInformationService getModelInformationService() {
if (modelInformationService == null) {
    modelInformationService = applicationContext.getBean(ModelInformationService.class);
}
```

the problem is that this bean has all @Autowired properties injected correctly:

```
 @Service
 public class ModelInformationServiceImpl implements ModelInformationService {

@Autowired
private EntityChangeService entityChangeService; // injected correctly

@Autowired
private PropertyService propertyService; // injected correctly

@Autowired
private ru.csbi.registry.services.reflection.HibernateDomainService hibernateService; // injected correctly
```

, but they are simple instances of java classes not Proxies supporting @Transactional annotation, which they are for my regular spring code:

```
 getModelInformationService().getClass().getName() is "ru.csbi.registry.services.impl.envers.ModelInformationServiceImpl"
```

and must be something like

```
$Proxy71
```

How to get transaction supporting proxies, which spring genereates for example when injecting beans in @Controller, in bean not managed by spring?

i'm using next spring config:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="lazyConnectionDataSourceProxy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="lazyConnectionDataSourceProxy" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy">
    <property name="targetDataSource">
        <ref local="dataSourceTarget" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceTarget" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ds.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${ds.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${ds.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ds.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${ds.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${ds.maxActive}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <!--property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="ru.csbi.registry.utils.audit.AuditLogInterceptor">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="auditSessionFactory" />
        </bean>
    </property-->
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="lobHandler" ref="oracleLobHandler" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="ru.csbi.registry.domain" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <bean id="hibernatePropertiesFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations">
                <list>
                    <value>file:${realtyregistry.settings.path}/hibernate-config.properties</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-insert" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
            <entry key="post-update" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
            <entry key="post-delete" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
            <entry key="pre-collection-update" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
            <entry key="pre-collection-remove" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
            <entry key="post-collection-recreate" value-ref="auditEventListener" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="auditEventListener" class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" />

<bean id="persistenceManagerHibernate" class="ru.csbi.registry.utils.PersistenceManagerHibernate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you want to ask, please make the question more clear. Please be so fair and spend at least so much time on formulating the question than you expect us to write the answers.

Comment: Is the instance you expect to be a proxy the instance you get by `applicationContext.getBean`, or is it an instance injected in anan field annotated by `@Autowired`?

Comment: Do you use Load Time or Compile Time Weaving AspectJ?

Comment: Both must be proxy. I need to get proxy by invoking applicationContext.getBean but that proxy is autowired with other beans which i need to be proxy too, because they too use transactional annotation.

Comment: Is the instance you expect to be a proxy (but seams to be not a proxy) the instance you get by applicationContext.getBean, or is it an instance injected in an field annotated by @Autowired? -- really I want to understand the problem.

Comment: applicationContext.getBean returns not a proxy. And this not a proxy has \@Autowired fields which are too not a proxy. And if i watch the same class as field of \@Controller class instance in debugger then it is proxy and its autowired fields are proxy too.

Comment: Do you use AspectJ or an other Byte Code Manipulation libary?

Comment: i use spring transaction api, so i dont configure aspectJ or byte code directly. Spring uses such functionality but i'm not into implementation. I just write <tx:annotationDriven in config and use HibernateTransactionManager

Comment: could you upload the complete code somewhere, so one could have a look on it?

Comment: i've posted config. You can debug spring sample app with transaction to see the proxies and invoke applicationContext.getBean there to see the difference. Sorry i cannot give all the code and have no time now to extract project with example for you.